Alexa automation with devices and api
I am trying to learn more about Alexa and automation capabilities.
I have a few IOT devices that I can control via Amazon Alexa app. I want to somehow get status of these devices to an api that I can access via http.
I have played around with Alexa development console and AWS Lambda but I’m pretty lost tbh.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Also do you need an Amazon hub to perform this? Or can the Alexa development console handle this?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
